# How to check if number is even or odd in Assembler

Tags: assembly, compare, division

I wrote a code to check if a number is even or odd, but my program contains a endless loop and I can't really find it.

Here are all Commands in the ISA:

[Commands Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk8MG.png)
[Commands Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jJKl.png)

Here is my Code:

```
#Read in Number
addi zero t0 1
sysmove exc t0
syscall

#Copy Number to a0
sysmove a0 I[0]

#check if number is even or odd
ldd t1 zero 0
ldd t2 zero 0
ldd t3 zero 1 #Register contains 1
ldd t4 zero 0 #Register contains 0

#divide:
subi a0 t2 2 # subtract with 2
ldd t2 a0 0 #move to a0
beq a0 t3 odd #compare a0 with 1
beq a0 t4 even #compare a0 with 0
jmp 6

#odd:
cout odd
syscall

#even: 
cout even
syscall
```

Answer (score 3):

Even vs. odd is determined by the lowest bit aka [Least Significant Bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Least_significant_bit).  If it is 0 then the number is even, otherwise (it is 1 and) the number is odd.

Normally, this single bit can be isolated using a simple AND immediate operation with constant mask 1, which would zero all the other bits except the LSB.  If you don't have an AND immediate, but have an AND, then you can load an immediate 1 value into a register and perform the (non-immediate) AND.

```
 1111110000000000
 5432109876543210    bit position
 ----------------
 abcdefghijklmnop    word of interest (to test for even odd)
                       note that bit "p" tells us even vs. odd
 0000000000000001
        &
 ----------------
 000000000000000p
```

Without AND operation, however, there are a number of other ways to isolate a single bit (or range of bits).  Here's one:

Shift left until it is the only remaining bit.  Shifting left will remove higher significance bits, while shifting in zeros.  Thus, if your computer is using 16-bit registers, then shifting left by 15 will result in the following value:

```
 abcdefghijklmnop    word of interest (to test for even odd)
                       note that bit "p" tells us even vs. odd
      << 15
 ----------------
 p000000000000000
```

This value can be compared to zero.  When the register zero, then p is zero, meaning the number was even, and when non-zero, p is non-zero, so the number was odd.

---

If we shifted left by only one bit we would get

```
 abcdefghijklmnop    word of interest (to test for even odd)
                       note that bit "p" tells us even vs. odd
      << 1
 ----------------
 bcdefghijklmnop0
```

So, if we do this same shift 15x we get to `p000...`.

You should be able to use `shli r1, r2, 15`.

---

If you like you can take that left-shifted value and shift it right.  With an arithmetic right shift the result will be:

```
p000000000000000
       >> 15 arithmetic shift
----------------
pppppppppppppppp
```

The arithmetic shift is appropriate for extracting signed fields.  (We rarely see a single bit signed field, of course, as 1 bit signed field can only represent -1 and 0!)

And with a logical right shift the result will be:

```
p000000000000000
       >> 15 logical shift
----------------
000000000000000p
```

This result restores the low bit to its former position (and gives the same answer as AND with an immediate of 1).  (However, we don't need to return the bit `p` to its original position just to test it against 0.)

---

The rotate instructions are handy to have if you want a loss-less shift.  These are particularly useful on machines that are poor in CPU registers, since the loss-less shift doesn't require an additional register to preserve original bits, in some scenarios.  But for extraction of a bit or field, we need a lossy operation, to loose or strip away bits, so the shifts do the job.

Comment: +1. @Kirby_Sikes: I can't see any equivalent of a CMP or an information on CPU 'flags' under the links provided. Is this a real CPU or some theoretical construct? If it's real you should add the architecture name into tags...